# Sharepoint 2010 - locate new site that haven't been checked in

Tags: 2010, provisioning

If a user create a new site and just saves is without checking the site in, where's the location?

I want to test what's happens if a farm administrator tries to publish a site that's not a "draft" or a published site. (got a custom "publish now"-button without having to go trough a workflow)

User 1 do this:
- create a new site (www.intranet.com/Pages/test1.aspx), then press ONLY save.

User 2:
 - tryes to create the same site test1 on the root. He got a "error" because the same site "exist".

So where is test1.aspx located? I can't manage to find it when I browse.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean with "where's the location"? Drafts are in the exact same place as the published content will be, with the only difference that unauthorized users can't see drafts whereas editors and contributors can. So if you have built a publish button, make sure it's only enabled for content which can actually be published (as is with the default publish button in document libraries).

Comment: @Jasper Hi, thanx for the answer. I know that drafts are located in the same place as the publised content will be. But where do the "before-draft" get's located? In a userprofile? 

I'll update my question.

Comment: So the "site" you are talking about is actually a page (test1.aspx), right? Pages are saved as drafts untill you publish them, there is no such thing as a before-draft status. But two users with contribute rights won't be able to see eachothers drafts. So if userA creates test1.aspx and userB also tries to create test1.aspx, an "already exists" exception will indeed occur. Only users with a higher level (editors, approvers, admins) will be able to see all non-published drafts.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a site without a template and select it later. The next time a person hits the URL, they are forced to pick a temlate to finish provisioning the site. You would need to navigate to www.intranet.com to provision the site, these should be listed in Central Admin, or if you list them all via Powershell.